# Saving U.S. Dollars or Mexican Peso - Mexican Citizen

Tags: investing, savings, usd-us-dollar

I have the habit of save money, I would like to invest that savings, but I live in Mexico, do you recommend me save U.S. Dollars or Mexican Pesos? You probably hear about the Mexican Peso crisis.

Comment: I would prefer dollars because I think the incoming US adminstration will cause the value/power of pesos to drop, not increase.  I would expect a dollar to but more pesos a year from now than it does today IF trade agreements are really on the chopping block.  This is pure speculation, of course.

Comment: Again, my comment is nothing more than pure speculation.  I am not a currency trader and have done no research on a dollar/peso play.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your goals. Without knowing more than the fact that you live in Mexico (and therefore presumably have future expenses in pesos) and that you are concerned about the purchasing power of pesos, I would suggest an inflation-linked peso-denominated investment, if one is offered.